# Query to check the consistency of records

Tags: sql, plsql

I have four tables

### TableA:

- id1
- id2
- id3
- value

### TableB:

- id1
- desc

### TableC:

- id2
- desc

### TableD:

- id3
- desc

What I need to do is to check if all combinations of id1 id2 id3 from table B C and D exist in the TableA. In other words, table A should contain all possible combinations of id1 id2 and id3 which are stored in the other three tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query evaluates all combinations of id1, id2 and id3 (the cross join) and finds which combinations are not present in table a.

```
select b.id1, c.id2, d.id3 from
 TableB b cross join TableC c cross join TableD d WHERE NOT EXIST
 (select 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.id1=b.id1 AND a.id2=c.id2 AND a.id3=d.id3)
```

EDIT: With an RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT allPerms.id1, allPerms.id2, allPerms.id3 FROM a RIGHT JOIN (select b.id1, c.id2, d.id3 from
 TableB b cross join TableC c cross join TableD) allPerms
 ON a.id1=allPerms.id1 AND a.id2=allPerms.id2 AND a.id3=allPerms.id3
 WHERE a.id1 IS NULL
```

The two are pretty much the same. Since we are not actually fetching values from the joined table, some people prefer the first approach, since it captures the intent and spirit of the query. The second version is more "implementation oriented". A good optimizer will produce an efficient plan for both, but on some lesser RDBMSs, the second version will run faster.

With a predefined set for table D - id3 has values (2,5,6)

```
select b.id1, c.id2 from
 TableB b cross join TableC c WHERE NOT EXIST
 (select 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.id1=b.id1 AND a.id2=c.id2 AND a.id3 IN (2,5,6))
```

But, this doesn't give you the id3 that is missing in the table A row. For that, I think the simplest is to emulate the table via a union, e.g.

```
select b.id1, c.id2, d.id3 from
 TableB b, TableC c, (select 2 id3 union select 5 union select 6) d 
WHERE NOT EXIST
 (select 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.id1=b.id1 AND a.id2=c.id2 AND a.id3=d.id3)
```

(This is still using cross join - it's implied if tables are separated by commas.)

Comment: I was trying to write this with inner join, would that have worked? If not please briefly explain what is the difference between these two? (sry for asking such a noob question)

Comment: An inner join will will find the values that are the same between two tables. You know which values you have (they're already in A) - you want to find which values you don't have. This means either an outer join (where missing values are joined as NULL) or an EXISTS subquery, like my first example. I've added an outer join example.

Comment: Thanks first all. I am still testing with my real scenario (which is still more complicated than the example above). I am still working on it. One more question: what can I do if the TableD does not exist, but I need to use a predefined set of id3, e.g. (2,5,6).

Comment: (union select 2 union select 5 union select 6) seems to be not working.

Comment: sorry, I was a bit too hasty...you'll need to add a column name. I've updated the example.

Comment: It's still not working with the union. Error message: invalid table name. could you help me?

Comment: remove the first union - see my update. Sorry about these syntax errors, but they are going to creep in when writing sql in a browser.

Comment: @orunner: you have a plsql tag on this question - does this mean you are using Oracle? If so, you will need the predefined set of id3 to be: (select 2 id3 from dual union all select 3 id3 from dual union all select 5 id3 from dual) - oracle *requires* a ...from table name... in a select clause; dual is a designated dummy table that always returns a single row.